# Using event handler for manually created component

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I'v been working on a project & decided to work in a unit file i have imported a few components & successfully used them, Only when trying to use the event handlers of the components i got lost.

I have researched & know it is possible i just don't know how & what i have to-do for example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Component;

var
Component: TComponent;

implementation

procedure Example1;
begin
Component:=TComponent.Create(nil);
//do something... 
end;

procedure OnComponentChangeEvent(Sender: TObject); <<<<  [Use event onchange of component]
begin
//do something...
end;  

end.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: use a components event handlers in code instead of using the default way... not sure how else to explain what i want.

Comment: Which event are you trying to provide an event handler for? Unless I am mistaken, `TComponent` does not surface any events.

Comment: TComponent is an example, pretend that TComponent holds events how would i code them in with no access to the TComponent's event handlers panel..

Comment: `component.OnSomething := SomeEventHandler;`